# Why there is no warning while casting with viewWithTag?

Tags: ios, xcode, viewwithtag

For example,

> UIImageView *iconView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:TestTag];

I remember that if I don't cast the type explicitly there will has warning before, but now Xcode doesn't show that, and my Xcode version is 7.1.1, is that a new feature or I modify some configs? who can tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new (Xcode 7) keyword in Objective-C, `__kindof`, that allows you to better express the return value of a method. Instead of `viewWithTag:` returning `UIView *`, it can return `__kindof UIView *` which tells the compiler something like:

> Accept any implicit downcast of the return type if the type is a `UIView` **or a subclass of `UIView`**.

Since `UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView`, no explicit cast is necessary. On the other hand, the following line of code will cause a compiler error because `NSDate` is not a subclass of `UIView`:

```
NSDate *date = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:TestTag];
```

Comment: So the IDE inserts the type casting for me? if viewWithTag returns a UILabel it also has no warning, it is also possible to get a wrong type, but I think the most important part is not whether there has explicit type casting,    which type you think it is is more important, and I can write less code with __kindof, thanks for your answer!

Comment: The compiler accepts the code without the type cast. This is really where it comes down to Objective-C vs Swift–Objective-C takes a looser (more unsafe) approach, whereas Swift is stricter (safer) and requires an explicit cast always.